# php Class name must be a valid object or a string

Tags: php, object

I'm trying to upgrade a site from PHP5 to PHP8.  Everything seems good so far, except for one issue in the login code.  I'm getting "Class name must be a valid object or a string" on line 443 in this code...

```
            // create the base object
            $baseObj = new $baseClass();
            $baseObj->attachToObject($tables[$baseTblAlias]['fields']);
            $baseObj->_exists = true;
            $tables[$baseTblAlias]['fields'] = array();

            $objectRefs = array();
            $lastObj    = null;

            // now create referenced objects and connect them with the base object
            foreach ($tables as $tblAlias => $tblData)
            {
                // skip the base table
                if (strcasecmp($tblAlias, $baseTblAlias) == 0) continue;

                // load field data into the object
                $className = $tblData['class'];
                $obj = new $className();
                $obj->attachToObject($tblData['fields']);
                $obj->_exists = true;

                // is the object joined with the base table or another table?
                if ($lastObj != null && strcmp($tblData['join_tbl'], $baseTblAlias) != 0)
                {
                    // add the object to the last object
                    if ($tblData['to_from'] == "from") {
                        $lastObj->_objrefs[$tblData['join_fks']] = $obj;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $lastObj->_objrefs[$tblData['class']][] = $obj;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // add the object reference to the base object
                    if ($tblData['to_from'] == "from") {
                        $objectRefs[$tblData['join_fks']] = $obj;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $objectRefs[$tblData['class']][] = $obj;
                    }
                }
                // save the object for any next iteration, DON'T USE REFERENCES HERE!
                $lastObj = $obj;
            }
```

Line 443, specifically:

```
                $obj = new $className();
```

This works properly in PHP 5.6, but will not work in 7 or higher.  I've tried pretty much everything under the sun to get this working, but apparently my Google skills are a bit lacking lately.  I've seen similar questions on here, but none of the answers on those questions seemed to help in this case.

```
class Sites_DB_User extends Sites_DB_Object
{
    /**
     * @var Integer
     */
    var $m_user_id = -1;
    /**
     * FK of the user's home country
     *
     * @var Integer
     */
    var $m_country_id = 0;
    /**
     * FK of the user's home region/state/province
     *
     * @var Integer
     */
    var $m_region_id = 0;
    /**
     * The user's name
     *
     * @var String
     */
    var $m_name;
    /**
     * The user's email
     *
     * @var String
     */
    var $m_email;
    /**
     * The user's password (md5 encoded)
     *
     * @var String
     */
    var $m_pass;
    /**
     * The user's website
     *
     * @var String
     */
    var $m_website;
    /**
     * The user's birthday date (ISO-8601)
     *
     * @var String
     */
    var $m_birthday;
    /**
     * The user's gender, either 'f' or 'm'
     *
     * @var String
     */
    var $m_gender;
    /**
     * A self-chosen comment on the user's profile page
     *
     * @var String
     */
    var $m_comment;
    /**
     * Registration datetime
     *
     * @var String
     */
    var $m_regdate;
    /**
     * Datetime of the last login
     *
     * @var String
     */
    var $m_lastlogin;
    /**
     * Activation phrase if this account was just created (md5 hash)
     *
     * @var String
     */
    var $m_actphrase;
    /**
     * Login count
     *
     * @var Integer
     */
    var $m_logincount;
    /**
     * Has the user uploaded a user image? y or n
     *
     * @var String
     */
    var $m_user_image = 'n';

    /**
     * Overridden attributes from the base class
     */

    /**
     * @var String
     * @access private
     */
    var $_table_name       = "users";
    /**
     * @var String/Array
     * @access private
     */
    var $_table_pkkeys     = "user_id";
    /**
     * @var Hash
     * @access private
     */
    var $_table_links_from = array(
        "country_id"    => "Sites_DB_Country",
        "region_id"     => "Sites_DB_Region"
    );
    /**
     * @var Hash
     * @access private
     */
    var $_table_links_to = array(
        "Sites_DB_Session" => "user_id",
        "Sites_DB_UserConfig" => "user_id",
    );
    /**
     * @var String
     * @access private
     */
    var $_class_name = "Sites_DB_User";

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @return Sites_DB_User
     */
    function Sites_DB_User() {
        parent::Sites_DB_Object();
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you `var_dump($className)`?

Comment: What is the value of `$className`? Paste the output of `var_export($className);`

Comment: dump - string(14) "Sites_DB_User"
export - 'Sites_DB_User'

Comment: Are you sure you've defined that class? Also, if it's in a namespace, the value needs to have the ```Namespace\ ``` prefix.

Comment: I just edited the original question with that class contents.  It does indeed exist.

Comment: Note that `class TestClass {} $className = "TestClass"; $obj = new $className(); print_r($obj);` does work in PHP8. Your error shows up if I use `$className = Array("TestClass")` instead, for example. Make sure `$className` is indeed a string. Your output says it is; but maybe the function is entered multiple times, and in one case it isn't? If the class was not found, a different error would be displayed.

Comment: This gives me a pretty good reason `string(14) "Sites_DB_User"` It says it is a string with 14 characters but the "Sites_DB_User" only have 13, so probably there is an empty space there causing this error. Try trimming the content of it first.

Comment: You also need to be aware that `Sites_DB_User()` is no longer considered a constructor, so it doesn't execute on `new`. You need to rename it to `__construct()`.